# Magnon spectrum with in-plane Dzyaloshinski-Moria interraction

Tags: quantum-spin, hamiltonian, bosonization, exchange-interaction

I'm attempting to derive a magnon spectra using first principles. In-plane DMI is considered in my system. $z$ axis is out of plane. First of all I wrote a Hamiltonian for interacting spins with two terms: Heisenberg exchange and DMI. Then I performed a Holstein-Primakoff transformation and obtained a Hamiltonian in bosonic operators, which contains 0,1,2,3,4 orders of operators. Heisenberg part results 0,2 and 4th orders and it's diagonalization is well defined in literature. But I do not understand what to do with DMI part which has form

$\hat{H}_{D}^x = \sum_{<i,j>} i D^{X}_{ij} (S (\hat{b}_j-\hat{b}^{+}_j+\hat{b}^{+}_i-\hat{b}_i) + 
    \hat{b}_i\hat{n}_j+\hat{n}_i\hat{b}^{+}_j - \hat{b}^{+}_i\hat{n}_j - \hat{n}_i\hat{b}_j +\\ 1/4(\hat{b}^{+}_j\hat{n}_j+\hat{n}_i\hat{b}_i - \hat{n}_j\hat{b}_j - \hat{b}^{+}_i\hat{n}_i) )$

How to obtain matrix for such Hamiltonian and diagonalize it analytically or numerically? How to treat with Hubbard like Hamiltonian in general form containing 1 and 3 orders?